# How can I get code to display on my English site but not my Spanish version?

Tags: php, template

I have two versions of the same site, one in English and one in Spanish and they share the same template.  One is www.mysite.com, the other www.mysite.com/es.

There is a Chat button (Moxie brand) on all the product pages, but the operators only speak English.  Despite text on the link that says English Only, the contact center gets ten plus chats per day in Spanish.  Not great service.

I'd like to figure out a way to wrap the chat code in a code that would hide it on the Spanish language pages.  Is it possible to test the URL for /es/ and if it is not there, go ahead and display the link.

Answer (score 1):

Admin -> System -> configuration -> top left, website scope -> spanish and disable your moxie module